# PRISM (ViewModel): Ensure a command does not get executed multiple times simultaneously

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, delegatecommand

I'm trying to disable frequent user gestures so the same command does not get executed multiple times simultaneously.

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1);             
public bool MyCommandCanExecute { get; set; } = true;
public DelegateCommand MyCommand { get; set; }

MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () =>
{
  await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

  try
  {
       MyCommandCanExecute = false;
       // run code
  }
  finally
  {
       MyCommandCanExecute = true;
       _semaphoreSlim.Release();
  }
}).ObservesCanExecute(p => MyCommandCanExecute);
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.

- Is `SemaphoreSlim` overkill or should I leave it there to be safe?
- Is `ObservesCanExecute()` needed since I'm manually turning the flag on and off?
- I have several commands in the same view model, each with a separate CanExecute flag. I'm thinking I will soon run into cases where one command needs to be enabled while another is running. Does `_semaphoreSlim` hold off all commands while one is in progress or does it hold off multiple invocations of the same command?

Answer (score 1):

- `ObservesCanExecute` works with properties that trigger `PropertyChanged` (it won't poll a regular property for changes)
- Your `_semaphoreSlim` let's one thread pass, no matter what command the thread is executing. So, if you want `CommandA` and `CommandB` to execute in parallel, but only one of each of them at a time, you'll need `_semaphoreSlimA` and `_semaphoreSlimB`
- As for `SemaphoreSlim` - if you want only one thread to pass, a `AsyncAutoResetEvent` would do the same thing but more understandable.
- If you do not want commands of a type to queue up, use `AutoResetEvent` and try to `WaitOne(0)`, aborting the command if you don't aquire the lock.

Comment: Just curious: Does anyone have some kind of 'best practice' implementation for this problem?